# Avoiding concurrent access to variable

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, eigen

Here is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <header.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main{

    int result(100);
    VectR M(100) = something; // VectR defined in header.h
    VectR N(100) = something else;

    #pragma omp parallel private(var,i,R) shared(M,N,result)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i){
            result(i) = somefunction(M,N(i));
        } 
    }
}
```

`somefunction`, defined in another file, will need to read (but not write to) the entire vector `M`.

**header.h:**

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

typedef double REAL;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<REAL, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> VectR;

int somefunction(const VectorR&, const VectorR&)
```

How can I avoid multiple threads from accessing a given element of `M` in `somefunction` at the same time? Some thoughts:

1. Could/should I simply put `#pragma omp critical` or `atomic` directives directly in the `somefunction` file where M is read?
2. My initial idea was to give each thread its own full copy of `M` by a clause `firstprivate(M)` in the `parallel` directive. However, I get the following error upon compilation:

   `main.cpp: In function âint somefunction(const VectorR&, const VectorR&)â:`

   `main.cpp:xx: error: âMâ has reference type for âfirstprivateâ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem?  Are you getting worse performance with OpenMP than without?  OpenMP has an overhead to use so if `somefunction` is fast and you're only running over 100 elements then OpenMP could give worse performance.

I don't see a problem with each thread accessing M.  As long as `somefucntion` does not write to M or N (only reads from them) there should be no problem.

You do, however, have a problem with false sharing in `result` but I don't know how much effect it has on your performance in your case without testing the full code.

Comment: Aren't concurrent reads to a given element of the shared variable `M` problematic? Also, I forgot to put `result` in the `shared` clause (code edited).

Comment: No, they should not be.  Each tread will pull values from M into its own cache.  You don't need to specify any of the shared or private variables in this case.  Variables defined outside of the parallel block are implicitly shared and variables defined inside the parallel block are implicitly private.  There are times you want to explicitly define them but not in your case.

Comment: Ah then I guess I have no problem then! Thanks for your help.
P.S. I've been told that explicitly declaring each variable in data-sharing clauses is good practice (at least for novice programmers).

Comment: Like I said, you may have a performance hit with false sharing.  But you should just compare performance with and without OpenMP and see how it scales.  If you expect a linear speed up proportional to the number of cores and you're getting much less then you may have a problem worth figuring out.

Comment: Indeed OMP is faster than serial, but does not scale linearly (e.g. 2 threads 3.49s, 8 threads 1.49s). Are you suggesting this may be due to false sharing?

Comment: How many cores do you have (don't confuse cores with hardware threads)?  You probably have four cores with hyper-threading so the most you should expect is a 4x speedup.  You can get a bit more with hyper-threading but probably no where close to 8x.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30859/discussion-between-lodhb-and-raxman)